# how to add listbox items to datagridview as it is in loop?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, listbox

I am sorry if the topic and my problem is missmatching but it is the best I can do.Anyways, I have 2 listboxes , 2 datagridviews, a chart,start and stop button and stopwatch. When I click start button listboxes getting datas(listbox1=data coming from serial port and listbox2=time(elapsed)) and real time charting is starting. When I push stop button all the values in listboxes copying to datagridview as seperated columns. Then If I click the start button again I want to clear all the previous data(from listboxes and datagridviews) to start with refreshed and new start.Then I start to get new data again as the same procedure (I mentioned before) until I click stop button. However there is a problem;when I click the stop button.In the new data(copied to datagirdview) I face that first row of the datagridview2 is the lastest row of the previous one. I mean in twice time of the measurement, It is saving the lastest row of the previous data (even I write to clear it) and adding it as a first row of the new measurement.In third measurement it gets the lastest row of the second one as a first row and it is going like that in every measurment.I dont know where the problem is? Can you help me?

```
    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        btnOpenFile.Enabled = false;
        btnStore.Enabled = false;
        btnSend.Enabled = false;
        btnStopReceiving.Enabled = true;
        btnStart.Enabled = false;
        btnTrig.Enabled = true;
        watch.Reset();
        watch.Start();
        zaman.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox2.Items.Clear();
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();

        foreach (var series in chrtAcq.Series)
        {
            series.Points.Clear();
        }
    }

    private void btnStopReceiving_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        watch.Stop();
        zaman.Enabled = false;
        timer1.Enabled = false;

        btnSend.Enabled = true;
        btnOpenFile.Enabled = true;
        btnStopReceiving.Enabled = false;
        btnStart.Enabled = true;


        btnStore.Enabled = true;
        btnSend.Enabled = false;
        foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[1].Value = item;

        }

        foreach (var item2 in listBox2.Items)
        {
            dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView2.Rows[dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0].Value = item2;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value =
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value;
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try binding the ListBox items to a BindingSource, then bind the BindingSource to the DataGridView.  This will update the DataGridView rows in real time as the ListBox items change.

Try replacing your foreach loops in the btnStopReceiving_Click method with this:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = listBox1.Items;
bs.ResetBindings(false);
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```